# Not able to implement Asynchronous XMLHttpRequest in Javascript in the right way

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I am using Async XMLHttpRequest to make an API call. Here's the workflow of my program,

```
first_function(){
var valueToBeReturned = 0;

 makeRequest(myCallback)//function for API call

 /*rest of the code*/
 console.log("print second");
 return valueToBeReturned;
}

function makeRequest(callback){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "my_url", true);
    xhttp.send(null);
    xhttp.onload = function() {
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4) {
            if(xhttp.status === 200) {
                response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                callback(null, response);
            }
        }
    }
}

function myCallback(data){
    console.log("print first")
}
```

Now what happens is every time I run it, the entire code in the first function is executed and then the code in makeRequest is executed. I understand JS is synchronous in nature and everything. But I'm not able to get my work done here, which is fisrt it makes API call, then callback is executed, then the code after makeRequest. What am I doing wrong here?

PS this is not the actual code, just to demonstrate the flow of my program

Comment: `makeRequest(){`…`}` — you forgot the `function` keyword and the `callback` parameter. JS is **a**synchronous in nature.

Comment: I'll edit my question. This is not the actual code, but just to demonstrate the workflow. I've written the same in the actual code @Xufox

Comment: So you have already working code for the `myCallback` callback. Put the code to be executed after the request in the callback.

Comment: You are probablly getting `print second` printed first before the  `print first`, which is not unexpected. That is how Async XMLHTTPRequest works.

Comment: Instead of returning the value `valueToBeReturned` I suggest you returning a promise. Read more about AJAX at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `callback` as a parameter in `makeRequest`. I'm not sure what that `null` is there for, though. If you want `"print second"` to print second, you'll need to execute it *after* myCallback - maybe insert another callback?

```
function first_function(){
  var valueToBeReturned = 0;
  makeRequest(myCallback, restOfTheCode)
  function restOfTheCode() {
    /*rest of the code*/
    console.log("print second");
  }
}

function makeRequest(callback1, callback2){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "my_url", true);
  xhttp.send(null);
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
      const response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      callback1(response);
      callback2(response);
    }
  }
}

function myCallback(data){
  console.log("print first");
}
```

But this whole thing would be a whole lot nicer if you used Fetch and Promises instead:

```
function makeRequest() {
  return fetch('my_url')
    .then(response => response.JSON())
}
// consume the request:
makeRequest()
  .then(responseJSON => {
     // do stuff with the responseJSON
   });
```

Comment: thnx both worked as expected. Also the null parameter indicates that no body content is needed for the GET request.